# Open source popup/panel for actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anybody have a solution for a popup (for a help panel)?  thanks.  this is in pure as3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ActionScript 3 to open an HTML popup do something like this:

```
var url:String = "javascript:openNewWindow('test.html','thewin', 'height=200,width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no')";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try {
  navigateToURL(request, '_blank'); // second argument is target
} catch (e:Error) {
  trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

I am not sure what you mean by pure ActionScript. Do you want the pop-up to be in the SWF? If so then you can create a sprite and show or hide it based on an event.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mean a popup like ads popup, but more like an alert box, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [PopUpManager of AS3Commons UI Layers](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/layers/). See also the [Tutorial: Creating an alert box with the AS3Commons PopUpManager](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/blog/tutorial-creating-an-alert-box-with-the-as3commons-popupmanager/).